# Ts create rest api interface stubs from json

Tags: angular, typescript

I saw in typescript there are a bunch of libraries (json2ts, maketypes) that allows to create an interface from a json object, but what if for a certain attribute i want to transform the output? Here an example:

for this json:

```
{
    "user": {
        "endpoint": "http://localhost:8000",
        "services": {
            "login": {
                "method": "POST",
                "path": "/login"
            },
            "logout": {
                "method": "GET",
                "path": "/logout"
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

i want the interface Services to look like:

```
export interface Services {
    login: Observable<any>;
    logout: Observable<any>;
}
```

and maybe create a proxy for my backend services without declaring and implement them one by one. As long as my be service responses are not really well defined i don't care of the kind of objects that comes out.

Is it possible? Are there some better strategies? I'm starting with angular6 and typescript now, before with plain js in angular 1.7 it was really easy to create a Backend Service dynamically to manage all http requests.
Thank you!